# Why is this algorithm O(N/2sqr)?

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, big-o

First post here. I am currently studying from a book called: A beginners guide to 'Data structures and algorithms'.

The following code is described as O(N²/2), and I understand that as constants are dropped it is simplified to O(N²), but I'm not sure why this code is considered as O(N²/2).

The idea of the algorithm is that it multiplies each value by the number to the right of it, which is why the inner loop starts 1 number after the outer loop.

Sample input : `[1,2,3,4,5]`
Sample output: `[2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,15,20]`

[image: image of code from book]

The idea of the algorithm is that it multiplies each value by the number to the right of it, which is why the inner loop starts 1 number after the outer loop.

Comment: Does the book literally say "N/2sqr"? This looks like a notation you have invented for your own question, not the notation used in a textbook, but if you invented it yourself then of course nobody here knows what it means. Also [please do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), post the actual code, formatted as a code block.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my formatting was wrong, I had meant O(N²/2). Will edit my post with this format.

Comment: It looks more like `n*(n+1)/2`

Comment: O(n²) is the number of times `push` is executed.

Comment: O(N²/2) implies that the person who wrote it doesn't really understand what O-symbol means.

Comment: Asymptotically, n*(n+1)/2 == n²/2 == n².

Comment: Time complexity analysis of a similar example beautifully explained by Abdul Bari: https://youtu.be/9TlHvipP5yA?list=PLDN4rrl48XKpZkf03iYFl-O29szjTrs_O&t=139

Comment: @bereal No, it implies that the person who wrote it is *explaining* big O notation using an example, if they then simplify it to O(n²). It's just as mathematically valid to write O(n²/2) instead of O(n²) as it is to write 1+1 instead of 2.